# Prepend element onto the beginning of an ActiveRecord Relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following

```
@blogs = Blog.all
```

I want to push an element onto the beginning of the that ActiveRecord Relation object.  This doesn't work as it would for an array:

```
@blogs.unshift(Blog.find(123))
```

How to I prepend a record within that activerecord relation object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
@blogs = []
@blogs << Blog.find(123)
@blogs += Blog.where.not(id: 123)
```

**Note:** `@blogs` remains as `array object` **not** `active record object`.

Comment: yes can do that way also, but `<<` this way pushing elements to array is more readable and easy to understand

Comment: `+=` will concatenate the given array while `<<` will push the given array to `@blogs`. In your solution you end up with something like `[blog1, [blog2, blog3]]` which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
@blogs = Blog.all.to_a
@blogs.unshift(Blog.find(123))
```